# Forest: draw=none doesn't work under \tikz+

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

The following MWE is based on an example in the `forest` documentation. The `dot` style (marked between `%%%` signs) is supposed take an argument specifying styles (primarily colors) for the dots in the tree. While it works for named colors, setting `dot={draw=none}` has no effect. Normally, setting `draw`/`fill` to `none` is supposed to draw/fill the path with no color.

What causes this curious effect? Does this have something to do with the fact that `dot` is defined using `\tikz+`?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks={elo}{}, % Edge Label Options
  anchors/.style={anchor=#1,child anchor=#1,parent anchor=#1},
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  dot/.style={tikz+={\draw[#1] (.child anchor) circle[radius=1.5pt];}},
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  decision edge label/.style n args=3{
    edge label/.expanded={node[midway,auto=#1,anchor=#2,\forestoption{elo}]{\strut$\unexpanded{#3}$}}
  },
  decision/.style={if n=1
    {decision edge label={left}{east}{#1}}
    {decision edge label={right}{west}{#1}}
  },
  text/.style={plain content},
  decision tree/.style={
    for tree={
      s sep=0mm,l=5mm,
      if n children=0{anchors=north}{
        if n=1{anchors=south east}{anchors=south west}},
      math content,
      /tikz/font=\footnotesize,
    },
    anchors=south, outer sep=2pt,
    dot={fill=white},for descendants={dot={fill}},
    delay={for descendants={split option={content}{;}{decision,content}}},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} decision tree
  [N,plain content
    [x;I,dot={draw=none,fill=red}] % 'draw=none' doesn't work here
    [x;I,dot={draw=red,fill=none}] % 'fill=none' doesn't work here
  ]
  % 'draw=none' works fine below
  \draw[draw=none](!1.anchor)--(!2.anchor)node[midway,above]{$x$};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry. My previous comment was singularly unhelpful. But I realised it was too long to fit the character limit so turned it into an answer. (Somebody voted it up, though?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`draw=none` works fine in `tikz+`, as it does in the `dot` style:

```
\begin{forest}
  [abc, dot={draw=none, fill=red}
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: red dot, no draw]

However, `tikz` is not the same as `tikz+`. `tikz+` is cumulative. Hence, if you say

```
for descendants={%
  dot={fill},
},
```

then, for all descendants of the current node (root here), the `dot` style is executed with `fill` as its argument and the following commands are added to the list to be used later:

```
\draw [fill] (.child anchor) circle [radius=1.5pt];
```

If you then apply `dot` again to a particular node, `dot` is executed again with the relevant argument. For example,

```
dot={draw=none, fill=red}
```

adds this to the list of TikZ commands to be used later:

```
\draw [draw=none, fill=red] (.child anchor) circle [radius=1.5pt];
```

So now what happens for this node is that both these commands will be used, one after the other, when the tree has been drawn:

```
\draw [fill] (.child anchor) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [draw=none, fill=red] (.child anchor) circle [radius=1.5pt];
```

The first draws and fills the circle in black. The second adds another circle, undrawn but with a red fill, in exactly the same place. So what you see in the output is *two* circles, one over the other.

If you want only the *last* use of `dot` to be effective, change the definition to use `tikz` rather than `tikz+`. However, the use of `dot` will then overwrite any *other* uses of `tikz`/`tikz+`/`+tikz` for the node. If this isn't a problem, the solution is thus very simple. If it is a problem, you'd need to do some more gymnastics to get it to work as desired or ensure that all invocations of `dot` occur *before* any other additions are made to the list of TikZ commands.

Here's the changed code for the straightforward case, which enforces a at-most-one-dot-per-node policy:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks={elo}{}, % Edge Label Options
  anchors/.style={%
    anchor=#1,
    child anchor=#1,
    parent anchor=#1,
  },
  dot/.style={%
    tikz={%
      \draw [#1] (.child anchor) circle [radius=1.5pt];
    },
  },
  decision edge label/.style n args=3{
    edge label/.expanded={%
      node [midway, auto=#1, anchor=#2, \forestoption{elo}] {\strut$\unexpanded{#3}$}
    }
  },
  decision/.style={%
    if n=1{%
      decision edge label={left}{east}{#1},
    }{%
      decision edge label={right}{west}{#1},
    }
  },
  decision tree/.style={
    for tree={
      s sep=0mm,
      l=5mm,
      if n children=0{anchors=north}{
        if n=1{%
          anchors=south east,
        }{%
          anchors=south west,
        },
      },
      math content,
      font=\footnotesize,
    },
    anchors=south,
    outer sep=2pt,
    dot={%
      fill=white,
    },
    for descendants={%
      dot={fill},
    },
    delay={%
      for descendants={%
        split option={content}{;}{decision,content},
      },
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  decision tree
  [N, plain content
    [x;I, dot={draw=none, fill=red}
    ]
    [x;I, dot={draw=red, fill=none}
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: only one dot per node!]